# change image name in DB table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would it be possible to change the name of an image that is already uploaded to a folder in DB? I want to have an input the user is going to write the name of the item lets say superhero and what I want is for the image name to be renamed in DB table and folder. superhero.jpg

```
 Name of item: <input type="text" name="Name>
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX (using jQuery) to update image name in database and folder.

Comment: Where can i find that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your complete system is, but assuming it's php+mysql you know the id of image entry in your database and at least thus the previous name of the file, you can make/edit your ajax file to do the job.

Here is what you should do

- Post the new name along with the file id or some other means of identifying the file and action to your ajax.php.
- In ajax, authenticate your user to prevent misuses.
- Make sure the filename is not reserved in the database or the folder so your data wont be messed up. Use php's file_exists() and check that a MySql query "SELECT if FROM files WHERE name = 'your-new-filename'" doesnt return rows. You dont want duplicates or errors, so better check for them before updating anything.
- Query some MySql like "UPDATE files SET name = 'newname' WHERE id = 123"
- Check that there are no database errors so the rename in database was successful.
- Update the filename on disk. You can use php's rename like rename('/path/to/old/file.name', '/path/with/new/file.name');
- Again, check errors & return a success or failure to the user.

This should do the trick. I hope this helps and i understoon your question correctly.

You should also read these

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

No matter what route you take, it boils down to a simple UPDATE of the table:
UPDATE $table SET image_name = '$_new_image_name' WHERE image_id = '$_iamge_id'